# publish an update only for specific versions of android?

Tags: android, developer-console

Is this possible to publish an update only for system versions above some API level? Say, I have an app with version 1.0, which have support from API 16 and then I want to release 1.1 update only for API 21 and above **AND I want to keep 1.0 for older devices as well** (so old version of my app will be visible on play store for old devices and new version will be visible for new devices). Is this possible in Google Play Dev Console?

Comment: I am not sure but in older versions of Google Play Developer Console there was advanced upload mode where you can upload multiple versions of your APK for differente configurations. Take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html

Comment: use minSDK version for the update, and not disable old APK

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic